# standard-error bars in bar plot not grouped

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to do a bar plot with bars for conditions 1 and 2 in x, filled with the two levels of V2,  with V3 corresponding to the counts in the y. V3 corresponds to the mean values and sds to the standard deviations.

```
df <- data.frame(V3 = c(0.87,0.78,0.9, 0.65),
                 V2 = c("A","B","C","D"), 
                 V1 = c("OT","OT","PL","PL"),
                 sd = c(0.3,0.4, 0.2, 0.1))

ggplot(df, aes(x=V1,y=V3, fill = V2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.2, position = "dodge")+
  ylim(0,1) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=V3-sd, ymax=V3+sd), width=.2)
```

This is what happens:

[image: aqui]

How can I solve this issue with the error bars? And also, change the colors of the bars?
It is also not doing anything when I add a label...

```
labs(x = "legendX", y = "legendY")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add position = position_dodge() inside the geom_errorbar.
Also, ylim cuts values outside the limits, and several ymax are >1, so they dissapear from the graph.
Added some nice colors NEJM style.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=V1,y=V3, fill = V2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.2, position = "dodge")+
  #  ylim(0,1) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=V3-sd, ymax=V3+sd), width=.2, position = 
  position_dodge()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#c7533b", "#5b86c3", "#9fc66d", "#e39e3e")) +
  labs(x = "legendX", y = "legendY")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! and were you able to label the axes?

Comment: Your suggestion should do it (+labs(x="X_axis legend", y="Y_axis _legend")) Just  remember the + sign in the row above. My guess is that you forgot it, else it should have worked. C.

Comment: Well.. it doesnt. It runs but doesent change anything

Comment: Updated the graph and code with legend changes